# Replace words/strings with links in JavaScript (or Ruby)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've consulted many SO posts, and I have a solution that's *almost* working.

I'm trying to swap words/phrases in a `<p>` tag with links after the page load with jQuery (but I'm open to a Ruby/Rails solution). Currently, I'm using `.html()` to swap the whole contents of the `<p>`, but I'm assuming I need to use `.replaceAll()` to swap just the term with a link so it doesn't overwrite the whole element.

```js
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  var terms = [{
    word: 'something',
    link: 'http://www.something.com'
  }, {
    word: 'something else',
    link: 'http://www.something.com'
  }];

  $.each(terms, function() {
    //find an element with id "linkSwap" that contains "word" (from array)
    $('#linkSwap:contains("' + this.word.toLowerCase() + '")')
      //substitute html with a nice anchor tag
      .html('<a href="' + this.link + '" target="_blank" data-test="asdf">' + this.word + '</a>');
    // .replaceAll("something", '<a href="' + this.link + '" target="_blank" data-test="asdf">' + this.word + '</a>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="linkSwap">
  Something and something else.
</p>
```

How do I grab the specific term to `.replaceAll()` it with my hyperlink instead of replacing the whole html?

Thanks, and please let me know if you need more information or more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider to use:

> [.html(function)](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function): A function returning the HTML content to set.
> Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old HTML
> value as arguments. jQuery empties the element before calling the
> function; use the oldhtml argument to reference the previous content.
> Within the function, this refers to the current element in the set.

The snippet:

```js
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    var terms = [{
        word: 'something',
        link: 'http://www.something.com'
    }, {
        word: 'something else',
        link: 'http://www.something.com'
    }];

    $.each(terms, function(idx, ele) {
        $('#linkSwap:contains("' + this.word.toLowerCase() + '")')
        $('#linkSwap:contains("' + this.word.toLowerCase() + '")').html(function(idx, txt) {
            var x = $.parseHTML(txt).map(function(n) {
                if (n.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    return n.textContent.replaceAll("something", '<a href="' + ele.link + '" target="_blank" data-test="asdf">' + ele.word + '</a>');
                } else {
                    return n.outerHTML;
                }
            }).join('');
            return x;
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/turbolinks/5.2.0/turbolinks.js"></script>


<p id="linkSwap">
    Something and something else.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. That gets me even closer, but the term info always returns undefined, and my url + tooltip are undefined too. It's like it can't find the `term` info when in the `return` line. Ideas?

Comment: Above the `$(#linkSwap:contains...)` line, I added `term = this;` and used `term.word`, `term.link`, and `term.info` in the link swapping line, and now it's building correct links for single words, but the phrases insert new links in the HTML overtop of the link that's there.  i.e. When it builds the link for `something else` and `something` already has a link, it will jack the link up because it creates a new link in the href property of the existing link.

Comment: @KyleCarlson Snippet updated. Let me know

Comment: Works perfectly! The only thing I'd like it to do now is handle both capital and lowercased words. I.e. if the word is `Something`, it should replace both `something` and `Something` with the term. I'm grateful for all your help!